# How to make a tool installed in one environment available in others using pyenv

Tags: aws-cli, pyenv

I upgraded pyenv recently (now at 1.2.14) and I've lost the ability to use the awscli command unless I have it installed on each environment.

Is there a way to have it installed on my global environment and have access to it while in another local environment?

It used to work but now I get the following error:

```
pyenv: aws: command not found
The 'aws' command exists in these Python versions:
<list of environments...>
```